# Renaming the title of the last Month column in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a "Months" as columns in my sheet and the last column correctly shows as "Jan 2018", "June 2018", etc. based on available data.

Now, how do I modify the title of this last column alone to "All Future Months" - because that is what the data means and this has become a very high priority for our business.

Comment: can you show screenshot?

Comment: Sorry, can't really show screenshot, but am hoping desc makes sense. I am talking about customizing the "column header text" of the very last column alone.

Comment: Are you using discrete dates or continuous dates?

Comment: It's discrete. Note that last column could be any month, based on the data.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these step:

- Right click on the column header you want to change and select Format.
- Change the Label on the bottom of the pane.

[image: See screenshot]

Comment: That only lets you edit the Total and Grand Totals label right? I want to edit the "last Month column" which ever it is based on the data loaded.